Thriller where husband hires hitman to kill wife at a weekend home by a lake
I've seen this movie about 5-6 years ago, it starts with the female protagonist (possibly a writer) showing her husband a tape recording about their dog. She's suffered through some trauma (maybe somebody's death?), and the husbands advises her to spend a few days at their holiday home at a lake. When she arrives, she sees something floating on the water, resembling their dog. Later she can't find it in the house. Then she's left alone and tries to work. 
She's scared to death when she finds a young man hiding in a wardrobe, holding the dog's coat, however, after questioning him, he gives good reasons why he was there. She then calls the police for him to be taken away. A man - claiming to be a sheriff -  arrives and escorts the youngster someplace else. 
Unbeknownst to the woman, the 'policeman' is actually a hitman, hired by her husband. After revealing this to her, she is chased through the whole estate, successfully hiding in the boathouse. The protagonist is then finally able to capture the hitman by trapping his arm in a garbage disposal unit, then turning it on, seriously wounding him and knocking him out. After regaining consciousness, he finds that he's been roped to a chair, unable to move, but his hand is cured. He tells the story about killing the dog and placing the blame on the young man (all of these were planned by her husband), while her husband arrives. 
She's shocked when he points a gun at her, while he exclaims that he will be above all suspicion since he'd brought a friend with him who will find her corpse dead already before they arrived. Then the wife surprises him by pulling a phone from her pocket. She'd called the husband's lawyer friend (sitting in his car in front of the house) and he's heard the husband confess to everything against her, being turned into a witness for the wife instead of being one for the husband.
I thought this movie had Diane Keaton as the protagonist, but I turned out to be wrong.

I'm not so sure but you could check A Perfect Murder directed by Andrew Davis. It's also about a man hiring someone to kill his wife.

@YnnaBorda please don't add answers as comments; use the "Your Answer" field to do that. If you want to know more about the site, please see [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

I think It is "Footsteps" of 2003
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365229/
I think the movie is this because: 1- the protagonist is a thriller writer spending a night alone at a beach house (not lake). She has many phobias because she was threatened by a man who said someone copied the crime in one of her novels, resulting in the death of someone close to him. 2- she can't find her dog and a fan has broken into her house hiding in a closet. 3-A cop showed up soon after that, saying that her husband called him. But he is not a cop. .

[edit] your answer to add more information, not in the comments

Ok, sorry :( The next time I will be more careful!

Looks like the correct movie to me. One reviewer even says that one of the characters "suffers a horrific injury to his hand. A towel is wrapped around it and the individual goes on as if nothing has happened."
